# how to get arrayobject specific data?

Tags: php, arrayobject

so far I always agreed to arrays with foreach but I do not know how to approach this.

could explain how it works

I have an objectArray:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["personaReturn"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
    ["datosGenerales"]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (8) {
      ["apellido"]=>
      string(11) "maxi rey"
      ["domicilioFiscal"]=>
      object(stdClass)#8 (6) {
        ["codPostal"]=>
        string(4) "1324"
        ["descripcionProvincia"]=>
        string(12) "BUENOS AIRES"
        ["direccion"]=>
        string(19) "hornos"
        ["idProvincia"]=>
        int(1)
        ["localidad"]=>
        string(5) "c.paz"
        ["tipoDomicilio"]=>
        string(6) "FISCAL"
      }
      ["estadoClave"]=>
      string(6) "ACTIVO"
      ["idPersona"]=>
      int(56871246)
      ["mesCierre"]=>
      int(12)
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(15) "reynoso"
      ["tipoClave"]=>
      string(4) "CUIT"
      ["tipoPersona"]=>
      string(6) "FISICA"
    }
    ["datosRegimenGeneral"]=>
    object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
      ["actividad"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#10 (5) {
          ["descripcionActividad"]=>
          string(41) "expensa"
          ["idActividad"]=>
          int(561014)
          ["nomenclador"]=>
          int(883)
          ["orden"]=>
          int(2)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(543)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#11 (5) {
          ["descripcionActividad"]=>
          string(149) "servicio de alimentacion"
          ["idActividad"]=>
          int(3423)
          ["nomenclador"]=>
          int(342)
          ["orden"]=>
          int(1)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(34532)
        }
      }
      ["categoriaAutonomo"]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (4) {
        ["descripcionCategoria"]=>
        string(40) "T1 CAT IV INGRES DESDE $15.001 A $30.000"
        ["idCategoria"]=>
        int(345)
        ["idImpuesto"]=>
        int(308)
        ["periodo"]=>
        int(34646)
      }
      ["impuesto"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#13 (3) {
          ["descripcionImpuesto"]=>
          string(26) "GANANCIAS PERSONAS FISICAS"
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(11)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(200710)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#14 (3) {
          ["descripcionImpuesto"]=>
          string(3) "IVA"
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(30)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(201312)
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
          ["descripcionImpuesto"]=>
          string(28) "APORTES SEG.SOCIAL AUTONOMOS"
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(308)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(200710)
        }
      }
    }
    ["metadata"]=>
    object(stdClass)#16 (2) {
      ["fechaHora"]=>
      string(29) "2017-12-15T15:12:06.157-03:00"
      ["servidor"]=>
      string(15) "aws.afip.gov.ar"
    }
  }
}
```

and i need to get some data of that. like: apellido, codPostal, direccion, nombre.

I do not know where to start.

Is there a function or method to do it?

can anybody hel me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
echo $obj->personaReturn->datosGenerales->apellido;

echo $obj->personaReturn->datosGenerales->domicilioFiscal->codPostal;

echo $obj->personaReturn->datosGenerales->domicilioFiscal->direccion;

echo $obj->personaReturn->datosGenerales->nombre;
```

Comment: Since it's an object array so you have to treat it like object and all indexes are fetched through `->`